# Is it possible to play a video without copying to client machine after executing..?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm having a video file that is added into Resources in my project.. After execution in client machine the video file is saved local.. When there is search using extension the file is visible.. I'm in need to hide or to protect it.. Please advice..

I got this piece of code from here only and it is working fine except writing the file to client machine.. Is there any possible solution that can be done to protect the file..

```
try
{
    string mp4Path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "64File.mp4");

    //check if it hasn't been written to disk yet

    if (!File.Exists(mp4Path))
    {
        //write it to disk

        File.WriteAllBytes(mp4Path, Offline_Video_Management.Properties.Resources._64);
    }

    textBox1.Text = mp4Path;

    //axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = textBox1.Text;
}
catch
{

}
finally
{
    axWindowsMediaPlayer1.enableContextMenu = false;
}
```

Comment: Where did you find the file after playing it? If you store it on disk to play it you could delete it after playing. It the media player stores it in its history I don't know enough about media player to say whether you could avoid this or not.

Comment: Normal in windows search in C Directory using the filename 64File..

It is stored in this location after executing.. I don't want this to be done as to prevent the master data..

Location : C:\Users\karthic\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\MNDMZQQL.V3L\T3CWHG18.318\offl..tion_fb93e40b47d1159c_0001.0000_a171541df0ba2780\64File.mp4

Comment: H.G. Sandhagen., That was a great idea by you to delete after playing it.. I observed that after uninstall of the s/w the file is removed from the installed location.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to store the resource on disk first you can serve it over HTTP if you leverage the [HttpListener](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener(v=vs.110).aspx).

Here is an example that serves byte stream from a dedicated url that you can control:

```
public static class LocalVideoServer 
{
    const string baseurl = @"http://localhost:50505/{0:N}/";

    static string url;

    // returns an url for a resource for the current running server
    public static string GetUrlForResource(string resource) {
      return url + resource;
    }

    static LocalVideoServer() {
        var http = new HttpListener();
        // clean up when we exit
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += (s,e) => {http.Abort();};
        // what url are we going to serve on
        // this url will be different of each run
        url = String.Format(baseurl, Guid.NewGuid());
        http.Prefixes.Add(url);
        // start handling local http requests
        http.Start();
        http.BeginGetContext(ContextCallBack, http);
    }

    // gets a specific resource based on the id
    static Stream GetResource(string id) 
    {
       Stream resource = null;
       if (id == "_64") {
         // get stream from embedded resource
         resource = new MemoryStream(Offline_Video_Management.Properties.Resources._64);
        } 
        else 
        {
           // some other (file) resource
           resource = File.Open(@"C:\what\ever\path\suits\here" + id, FileMode.Open);
        }
        return resource;
    }

    // server http requests
    static void ContextCallBack(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        var http = (HttpListener) result.AsyncState;
        http.BeginGetContext(ContextCallBack, http); // listen for the next connection

        var ctx = http.EndGetContext(result);

        var requestUrl = ctx.Request.Url.ToString(); // the url 
        var resource = requestUrl.Substring(requestUrl.LastIndexOf('/') + 1); // find the "id"

        ctx.Response.ContentType="video/mp4"; // assume we always return an mp4 video
        ctx.Response.StatusCode = 200;  // success

        using(var stream = GetResource(resource)) // we want to close resources
        {
            stream.CopyTo(ctx.Response.OutputStream); // send the resource as is to Windows Media Player
        }
    }
}
```

The above class would be used in your example as follows:

```
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = LocalVideoServer.GetUrlForResource("_64");
```

where this time the URL could be

```
http://localhost:50505/f3248e3864b14448a9512736796b1f9b/_64
```

and that URL will work as long as your app runs. The bytes are served from memory so you won't have to worry about files being left on disk. When your application exits the URL is no longer usable.